# Issue with RDweb on IE

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdweb

I am working on RDWeb Access.I have made two servers,both of them are configured for rdweb.Now i am trying to access the weeb feed of server-2 through the RDWeb access application of Server-1.I am able to access the server-2 webfeed.in ie the icons for server-2 webfeed are not shown,also when i click the icon it gives following error.

can anyone help me out resolve this issue.
Thank you for sharing your time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DO you have IE enhanced security switched on? Can be checked in Server Manager>Local server>IE enhanced mode and set to off for users/admins.